# Using the API, how do I know a customer has a credit card on file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

When someone currently signs up for a server, they click on a plan and a popup is displayed with the stripe checkout popup (which asks for the credit card information etc)

If someone is updating their plan, I don't need to display the stripe checkout popup.  How can I determine that not only does the customer exist in stripe, but they have a credit card in stripes system so I can just update/change their plan without asking them to re-enter their credit card details.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating a Stripe Customer and storing the Stripe customer id in your users table.  Here I am assuming your customers/users are part of a `User` model and tracked in the `users` table in your database.

The Stripe documentation has a [recipe](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/rails) for creating a Stripe customer.  We will draw on that here.

First, you will want to add the [Stripe gem](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby) to your Gemfile.

Next you will want run a migration to add a string column to your `users` table called `stripe_customer_id`.

Next add the following to your User model:

```
def get_or_create_stripe_customer!(stripe_token, stripe_email = nil)
  return self.stripe_customer_id if self.stripe_customer_id.present?
  stripe_email = self.email if stripe_email.nil?

  customer = customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    :email => stripe_email,
    :source => stripe_token,
  )

  self.update_attribute(:stripe_customer_id, customer.id)
  return customer.id
end
```

From your controller that processes payments you can call

```
current_user.get_or_create_stripe_customer! params[:stripe_token], params[:stripe_email]
```

This will either create a new Stripe customer or to retrieve the Stripe customer id.  NOTE: In this code sample, `current_user` is a variable representing the user who is logged in.

You can simply query `current_user.stripe_customer_id.present?` to determine if the customer has a credit card on file.  You can also use the `stripe_customer_id` to create future charges.

The [Stripe Charges documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/charges) can walk you through more details on creating Stripe customers (i.e. keeping credit card info on file) and on creating new charges using a Stripe customer id.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a column to your customers table that carries a value of true or false, and when a customer is created, it can create a default value of false. When a customers card is confirmed to be on file, then that value can change to true.